# Creating the door of a castle

Tags: modeling

This is what I'm trying to model:

[image: castle]

I'm stuck here. I don't know how to go about creating the door of the castle. I've tried adding the cavity with a boolean modifier and solidifying the edges around, but the result is far from acceptable.

What is the smartest way to go around this? Subdivide->Knife?

PD: I added the .blend file just in case you want to give it a try. I'm interested in learning the process, not in having the result finished. I'm here to learn.

**FILE:**

[image]

Comment: You want it to be low or high poly?

Comment: Hey @LukeD. I want to make it Low-poly. But I'm more interested in the process than in getting the final model. I thought making the door would be easy, but it is not. At least not for me. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, let me ask couple more questions. Do you want to cut a hole in it and then add doors or could it be just extrusion? And do you need some help for stones around doors?

Comment: I just need the hole, don't worry about the brown doors. Just the hole. And yes, some help with the stones would be welcome! But I haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to *Edit Mode* and select desired faces. For example:

[image: First]

2. Press <kbd>X</kbd> and *Remove Faces*.
3. Change *Transformation Orientation* to *Normal* (a). It will help to reduce distortion of the mesh.
4. Enable *Proportional Editing* (b).
5. Grab handles and position vertices (c). You can use mouse scroll to change size of the influance ring.

[image: second]

[image: third]

### Update:

1. Turn off *Proportional Editing* and change *Transforamtion Orientation* to *Global*.
2. Select loop around cutted hole.

[image: fifth]

3. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude it along *Y axis*.
4. Now turn on *Snap* and choose *Vertex*.

[image: sixth]

5. We need to remove the vertex that is overlaping our mesh. To do so, grab it and position over the nearest vertex, then hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole mesh and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.
6. To make face and complete frame select vertex point, extrude it along *Z axis* (<kbd>E</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> and hover cursor over another vertex on the bottom). Now select all 4 of them and hit <kbd>F</kbd> to make a new face.

[image: seventh]

Comment: Hey @LukeD, thanks for the answer. I already tried that on my own. Problems start when I try to make the border of the door. I tried extruding the edge loop, and solidify but the resultant mesh is a complete mess. Ideas?

Comment: @JosePerez I've made an edit.

Comment: Thank you VERY much, that was the part I couldn't do by myself :)

Comment: @JosePerez think about changing top part of the mesh, I see that you have used boolen for this and now there are ngons and tris. Not to good for my taste. You can easly create such mesh by creating cylinder (30 vertices) with Cap Fill Type > Nothing, then select top loop, press E > S scale it a bit and then select 4 faces - 2 faces gap - 4 faces - 2 faces gap etc. Extrude selection up and here you have nice clean mesh :)